# How can i extract data from table where some column is start and end xml tag and some column is xml element of those tags?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

How can i extract data from follow table stored in Oracle database

```
id   | id_sttt_optp_trmt  | Description            | ctype 
    
 1   | OPTP5101           | Them-on-us Sale POS    | OPTP
 2   | OPTP5102           | Them-on-us Refund POS  | OPTP
 3   | OPTP5103           | Them-on-us MSC POS     | OPTP
 4   | OPTP5102           | Them-on-us Cashout POS | OPTP
```

like this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
    <xml_cfg>
        <global_params>              
            <param>
                <name>OPTP</name>
                    <value>
                        <OPTP5101>Them-on-us Sale POS</OPTP5101>
                        <OPTP5102>Them-on-us Refund POS</OPTP5102>
                        <OPTP5103>Them-on-us MSC POS</OPTP5103>                            
                        <OPTP5121>Them-on-us Cashout POB</OPTP5121>
                   </value>
            </param>
      </global_params>
    </xml_cfg>
```

I need pl/sql procedure that return clob that content this xml.

If anyone knows please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLTABLE` in an SQL query (you do not need PL/SQL or a procedure):

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '/xml_cfg/global_params/param/value/*'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.value)
         COLUMNS
           id                 FOR ORDINALITY,
           id_sttt_optp_trmt  VARCHAR2(30)  PATH 'name()',
           Description        VARCHAR2(200) PATH 'text()',
           ctype              VARCHAR2(10)  PATH './../../name'
       ) x
```

Which, for the sample data (with the DTD removed):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS 
SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xml_cfg>
        <global_params>              
            <param>
                <name>OPTP</name>
                    <value>
                        <OPTP5101>Them-on-us Sale POS</OPTP5101>
                        <OPTP5102>Them-on-us Refund POS</OPTP5102>
                        <OPTP5103>Them-on-us MSC POS</OPTP5103>                            
                        <OPTP5121>Them-on-us Cashout POB</OPTP5121>
                   </value>
            </param>
      </global_params>
    </xml_cfg>' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | ID_STTT_OPTP_TRMT | DESCRIPTION | CTYPE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | OPTP5101 | Them-on-us Sale POS | OPTP |
> | 2 | OPTP5102 | Them-on-us Refund POS | OPTP |
> | 3 | OPTP5103 | Them-on-us MSC POS | OPTP |
> | 4 | OPTP5121 | Them-on-us Cashout POB | OPTP |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=44d9dd8d4fcca7e58701456629d6e0d6)*